# Describing 'fit' and 'suit'

Tags: word-choice

Is it grammatically correct to say:

'This coat fits me very much'

and

'This coat suits me very much'
?

I know the difference between 'fit' and 'suit', I'm only interested in using 'very much' with them

Comment: With "very much", *suits me* is more idiomatic, but they would mean about the same thing--it is holistically a good match. If the first was "This coat fits me" or "this coat fits me very well", the statement would be more sensible and would refer specifically to the size and cut being a good match for the wearer's body. "This coat suits me" could mean, "it matches my taste", "I think it makes me look good", "it fulfills the purpose I have", etc.

Answer (score 4):

The two words mean different things.

> Clothes **fit** you If they are sized correctly for all parts of your body.
>
> Clothes **suit** you if they are of a style etc. that makes them look good on you.

It is possible for clothes to fit you badly but suit you well, if a baggy clothing style works well for you.

"Fits" should not generally be used with "much" because fit is not usually quantitative - fit is good or bad but one fit is not 'more' than another.